# Text from pdftotext and alignment

Tags: pdf, alignment, xpdf

I used texttopdf on linux to extract all the text from a multipage pdf, everything is fine, except that each page get a different alignment, although in the original pdf this is not the case, here is a sample from the first 3 pages:

```
                         Instructor First                          Number Students Who   Number Students Who
Subject Course Section                      Instructor Last Name                                               A    B C       D F
                         Name                                      Completed the Class   Dropped the Class
ACCT    201    01        Karin              Hatheway Dial          56                    6                     19   9    16   2   5
ACCT    202    01        Karin              Hatheway Dial          69                    11                    37   14   7    2   6
ACCT    205    01        Darryl             Woolley                20                    1                     3    7    6    1   3
ACCT    205    02        Darryl             Woolley                28                    1                     6    7    13       2
ACCT    205    03        Darryl             Woolley                42                    5                     4    13   21   1   3
ACCT    205    04        Darryl             Woolley                23                    1                     9    5    8    1
ACCT    205    05        Darryl             Woolley                30                    2                     11   7    9    2   1
ACCT    205    06        Darryl             Woolley                25                    3                     8    9    6    1   1
ACCT    275    01        Darryl             Woolley                33                    2                     7    15   9    1   1
ACCT    310    01        Marla              Kraut                  16                    1                     1    6    7    2
ACCT    310    02        Marla              Kraut                  64                                          5    43   15   1
ACCT    310    03        Marla              Kraut                  72                    3                     11   47   10   3   1
ACCT    311    01        Karin              Hatheway Dial          45                                          13   20   11   1
ACCT    311    02        Karin              Hatheway Dial          25                                          10   12   3
ACCT    315    01        Jason              Porter                 26                                          6    5    8    6   1
ACCT    315    02        Jason              Porter                 29                    1                     6    10   5    7   1
ACCT    414    01        Teresa             Gordon                 22                    1                     6    6    9    1
ACCT    483    01        Glen               Utzman                 26                    1                     7    13   6
ACCT    486    01        Teresa             Gordon                 33                                          13   14   6
ACCT    492    01        Jason              Wills                  23                                          5    8    9    1
ACCT    515    01        Jeffrey            Harkins                15                                          7    6    1
ACCT    561    01        Jason              Porter                 18                    1                     10   7    1
ADOL    526    13        Charles            Gagel                  21                    2                     19   1             1
ADOL    573    13        Martha             Yopp                   28                                          16   3             1
ADOL    574    01        Laura              Holyoke                16                                          12   3             1
ADOL    574    11        Laura              Holyoke                9                     1                     8    1
ADOL    574    13        Laura              Holyoke                15                                          10   4             1
ADOL    600    13        Roger              Scott                  19                                          4         1
AERO    101    01        William            Beauter                11                                          8    2    1
AERO    103    01        Sarah              Babbitt                15                                          7    6    1        1
AERO    411    01        Sarah              Babbitt                11                                          6    4    1
AERO    413    01        Sarah              Babbitt                12                                          8    3    1
AGEC   101   01   Larry         Van Tassell   36    1    20   15        1
AGEC   278   01   Larry         Makus         21    1    2    6    8    5
AGEC   278   02   Larry         Makus         18         5    10   2    1
AGEC   278   03   Larry         Makus         17    1    2    7    5    2    1
AGEC   301   01   Christopher   McIntosh      18         9    4    5
AGEC   356   01   Joseph        Guenthner     23         15   6    2
AGEC   361   01   Ruby          Stroschein    11         4    1    6
AGEC   411   01   Robert        Haggerty      11         6    4    1
AGEC   413   01   Robert        Spear         12    3    4    5    2    1
AGEC   415   01   Larry         Van Tassell   11         10   1
AGEC   526   01   Scott         Matulich      7          2    5
AGEC   527   01   Stephen       Cooke         5          3    2
AGED   180   01   Lori          Moore         23    1    14   5    1    3
AGED   351   01   Lou           Riesenberg    11         4    6    1
AMST   301   01   Walter        Hesford       26         14   8    3         1
ANTH   100   01   Mark          Warner        104   15   31   31   21   8    12
ANTH   220   01   Fumiyasu      Arakawa       138   4    48   53   19   10   8
ANTH   230   01   Robert        Sappington    28    1    7    9    9    2    1
ANTH   251   01   Donald        Tyler         36    1    10   14   8    1    3
ANTH   420   01   Laura         Putsche       12         3    4    2         2
ANTH   422   01   Rodney        Frey          13         11                  2
ANTH   427   02   Virginia      Babcock       13    1         2    6 4       1
ANTH   462   01   Laura         Putsche       33    3    8    20   3 1
ARBC   101   01   Anisah        El-Mansouri   14    1    8    5    1
ARCH   151   01   Randall       Teal          150   8    72   40   13 6      19
ARCH   253   01   Roman         Montoto       23    1    9    10   2         1
ARCH   253   02   Randall       Teal          22    2    9    11   2
ARCH   253   03   Xiao          Hu            23    2    11   12
ARCH   353   01   Matthew       Brehm         16         7    7    1
ARCH   353   02   Dillon        Ellefson      16         4    11   1
ARCH   353   03   Xiao          Hu            10         4    6
ARCH   385   01   Anne          Marshall      68    5    29   22   11 2      4
ARCH   404   04   Matthew       Brehm         10         1    5    3 1
ARCH   453   01   Roman         Montoto       10         5    4    1
ARCH   453   02   Anne       Marshall              13        6     5             1
ARCH   463   01   Phillip    Mead                  63    1   26    31   5 1
ARCH   465   01   Kenneth    Carper                51    1   8     26   12 3
ARCH   483   01   D.         Reese                 71    2   27    35   8
ARCH   504   02   Randall    Teal                  15        9     6
ARCH   504   03   Kevin      Van Den Wymelenberg   6         3     1             1
ARCH   504   04   Frank      Jacobus               12    1   8     4
ARCH   510   02   D.         Reese                 13        9     4
ARCH   510   04   Robert     Thornton              9         7     1
ARCH   510   05   Roman      Montoto               11    2   7     4
ARCH   553   01   Bruce      Haglund               14        12    2
```

as you can see, the alignment changes in each page, what I would like to achieve is a single alignment for all pages, is it possible?
I tried using expand -8, sed with different patterns, but to no avail.

Thanks,

Comment: Personally, I think it's time to whip up a small script to postprocess it.

Comment: Well, thats what I'm trying, with Perl, but to no avail. even: http://stackoverflow.com/users/427306/soulsurfer2010 with no success.